# Delete old backups with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, cron

I am new to bash scripting and i am trying to write a script that deletes backup files on a server that are older than x number of days. At the moment i have set the number to 7 but that would likely change. The script would eventually be executed with crontab. It should meet the following requirements.

- Delete files older than x number of days
- However, at all times there should be atleast 3 backup files present. So if the backups are less than 4, the script should not delete them.

I tried solving the above with the code below

```
#!/bin/bash
unset all_backups_count
unset old_backups_count 
unset increment_old_backups_count
all_backups_count="$(find -type f | wc -l)"
old_backups_count="$(find -mtime +7 -type f | wc -l)"
increment_old_backups_count=$((old_backups_count + 3))
if [ "$all_backups_count" -ge 3 ] && [ "$increment_old_backups_count" -le "$all_backups_count" ];then 
  echo "deleting ${old_backups_count} old backup files"; 
  find -mtime +7 -type f -delete; 
  echo "success"; 
fi
```

The above script works to an extent, however in cases where backups are older than x number of days (in this case 7), it fails to delete any backups at all. The best scenario should be;

- If backup files are more than 3 and all older than 7 days, then the most oldest backup files should be deleted until it is left with only 3 backup files which should be the most recent.
- Also, I am sure my script needs a lot of refactoring

Comment: Can you please post output of `ls -al` command called in directory when you want to do cleaning in that case you think your script is failing? Also did you try running script with `bash -x`?

Comment: Maybe keeping only 3 newest files in directory is enough for you? If so you can use this one liner `rm $(find . -type f -printf '%Ts\t%p\n' | sort -nr | cut -f2 | tail -n +4)`, if it is not enough please inform me which case I am missing.

Comment: I've tried your code directly (well..listing instead of deleting though :) )... and it works as is. I had 10325 files total, 10320 old files and it wanted to delete all the old ones. Can't see a problem...by the way, if I may, I would specify the directory for your find directive, when it comes to deleting files, I'm a bit paranoid :D.

Comment: Counting files with `wc -l` is problematic, if there are newlines in file names. Either move to `-printf "\n" | wc -l` or make sure you never put newlines in the names of backup files.